# Excel (VBA) - UserForm Combobox > Listbox, stop duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

Upon selecting a category from a combobox a listbox then updates with only records related to the combobox selection. However the list is producing duplicates and I was wondering how I prevent this from happening.

```
Private Sub ProdComp_Change()
Dim RowMax As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim countexit As Integer
Dim cellcombo2 As String
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("products")
RowMax = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Me.LBType.Clear

With LBType
    For i = 2 To RowMax
        If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = ProdComp.Text Then
        .AddItem ws.Cells(i, "c").Value
        Else
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

[Worksheet View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqS9l.jpg)

[UserForm View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yG2y.jpg)

Comment: Please show some examples. Also, are you sure that there are no duplicates in your column B?

Comment: I have added two images, as you can see because each product has different variations, what I want to prevent happening is as you can see in the "UserForm View" to have each product type only show once as opposed to showing numerous times. However, as it is currently designed needs to accommodate for any new additions made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may give this a try...

```
Private Sub ProdComp_Change()
Dim RowMax As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim countexit As Integer
Dim cellcombo2 As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim dict

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("products")
RowMax = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Me.LBType.Clear

With LBType
    For i = 2 To RowMax
        If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = ProdComp.Text Then
            dict.Item(ws.Cells(i, "c").Value) = ""
        End If
    Next i
    If dict.Count > 0 Then .List = dict.keys
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That has worked perfectly! Thank you, I have been wracking my brain on how to do this correctly!

Comment: @R.Langdell You're welcome! Glad it worked as desired. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the items to a unique collection and then add the collection to the listbox. This way you will not get any duplicates.

Try this

```
Private Sub ProdComp_Change()
    '~~> when working with Rows, Please do not use `Integer`. Use `Long`
    Dim RowMax As Long, countexit As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cellcombo2 As String
    Dim col As New Collection, itm As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("products")
    RowMax = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To RowMax
        If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = ProdComp.Text Then
            '~~> On error resume next will
            '~~> create a unique collection
            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add ws.Cells(i, "c").Value, CStr(ws.Cells(i, "c").Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next i

    Me.LBType.Clear

    If col.Count > 0 Then
        For Each itm In col
            LBType.AddItem itm
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

If you have too much of data then you can copy the data to the array instead of looping through rows and then create the unique collection.

[image]